# I don't know why OnDraw() function is called in repetition

Tags: c++, api, mfc

Here's the code:

```
void PinNameView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    if(!AdPinData::getFlag()) return;

    for(int i=0; i<numOnPins; i++)
        pButton[i].ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, CSize(timeFrame*gridX,0));
}
```

and here is the `OnUpdate()` function which sets the pin names into the button boxes when it gets pin names from the text file.

```
void PinNameView::OnUpdate(CView* pSender, LPARAM lHint, CObject* pHint)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    if(!AdPinData::getFlag()) return;

    numOnPins = AdPinData::getOnPinSize();
    pt_Pin = AdPinData::getPinDataPtr();
    if(pButton) delete [] pButton;          //initialize pButton if the pointer has a last value
    pButton = new CButton[numOnPins]();
    for(int i=0; i<numOnPins; i++){         //to write pinName into each buttons
        string str = pt_Pin[i].pinName;
        pButton[i].Create((CString)str.c_str(),WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_BITMAP/*BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON*/,
            CRect(0,i*gridY,98,(i+1)*gridY),this,i);
    }
    this->Invalidate(false);
}
```

and when running in debug mode, I found that the `OnDraw()` function is called in repetition. After `SetScrollSizes()` function, it goes into the start of `OnDraw()` function again, and it repeats around 40-50 times.

I don't really understand what's going on.

Comment: How do you know that the function is called repetitively? Do you have a breakpoint in the function, and every time you continue the breakpoint is hit again? That might be because Visual Studio (I'm guessing you use VS?) window is most likely obscuring the window of your program, and when you continue your window is brought to the front but because it was obscured it needs to be redrawed so `OnDraw` is called and you hit your breakpoint. And so on and on and on...

Comment: Well.. OnDraw is called everytime it needs to draw, if you're debugging and covering/moving the window/changing focus it will need to redraw more..

Comment: Don't call `SetScrollSizes` directly from `OnDraw()`. It is real bad practice. Call `SetScrollSizes` when the contents changes in a way that requires the scroll position to change, then use the scroll info in `OnDraw`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course I can know, when I check it with another monitor. In debug mode, the window is not activated until there're still codes to execute, and all the instructions are finished than the window is activated again while waiting some events. However, in my program, it was supposed to activate the window after only one time the **OnDraw()** function executed, but after 40-50 times, the **OnDraw()** function did.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin Why I shouldn't call **SetScrollSize()** from **OnDraw()** ? Actually, **SetScrollSizes()** is way better easy and simple code. Calling **SetScrollInfo()** needs a lot of codes and steps, so I didn't consider it. I used CScrollView class, but if there're something that I've missed, please let me know.

Comment: @Sean: Read this: http://msgroups.net/vc.mfc/cscrollview-setscrollsizes/559558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `SetScrollSizes` directly from `OnDraw()`. It is real bad practice. Call `SetScrollSizes` when the content changes in a way that requires the scroll position to change, then use the scroll info in `OnDraw`.

Otherwise, you'll end up having endless cycles as the `OnDraw` decides that the scroll sizes change, which changes the amount of information displayed, which requires `OnDraw` be called, which then, as a consequence of the change, changes the scrolling sizes, which then means that information has to be redisplayed.